# RouterLink problem with dynamic values ( load timing issue? )

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, angular2-routing, ionic4

I have an IONIC-4 / Angular 7 project, with the following `routerLink`;

```
<p>{{ data?.name }}</p>
<ion-button [routerLink]="['/', 'tabs', 'projects', data?.name]">Configure Project</ion-button>
```

In the running page, the first `{{ data?.name }}` appears fine, however in the `routerLink` it evaluates to `undefined`.

I suspect it's a load-timing issue, i.e. on the first pass of template rendering, data isn't yet loaded so it's `undefined`, and on the second pass all is good.  However `routerLink` doesn't pick up the updated data.

There must be a better approach to the load?  Data is coming from a REST API, as follows-

in **page.ts**;

```
data: any;

ngOnInit() {

    this.projectService.getProject(this.id)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.data = res; 
      });

}
```

The underlying `projectService` uses the API;

```
getProject(id: string): Observable<any> { 

  return this.http
    .get(`${this.endpointUrl}/${id}`);

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try the followings -

1. Please check if your `@Component` decorator is having following property set - `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` - If it is set then remove `changeDetection` property and its value and try your code.
2. Hope it should work. If it does not work or `@Component` is not having `changeDetection` property set then please update your code like this-

   `data$: Observable<any>;
    ngOnInit() {
     this.data$ = this.projectService.getProject(this.id);
   }`

Update your template like this -

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <ion-button [routerLink]="['/', 'tabs', 'projects', data.name]">Configure Project</ion-button>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks @user- on #1, no there is no `changeDetection` property set on the page `@Component`.  On #2, very interesting, I've not seen the `data$` variable declaration before. I will look into that to understand it better.

I have been avoiding `Observable`s here since they seem to complicate my Create and Update UI patterns, at least I haven't found a good way to push data into the Observable object 

**However**, for some reason, after a few hours of trying to debug this, the problem suddenly went away.  I am wondering if it's possible there was something "stuck" in the built files?

Comment: @Memetican `$` after the variable is just to say that this variable is an Observable. I would recommend using Observables as it is in the core of Angular. If you refer `async` pipe [https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe] then you would find that Angular team has done awesome work to subscribe/unsubscribe the observable automatically by having `async` pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but after a few hours of trying different approaches to this, the `routerLink` problem went away, and it is currently working as expected.

My working design remains unchanged, except that since `data` is loaded asynchronously, I am pre-checking load with `*ngIf`.

`data` has to be populated before I allow Angular to attempt constructing the `routerLink`.

```
<ion-button *ngIf="data" [routerLink]="['/', 'tabs', 'projects', 'edit', data?._id]">Configure Project</ion-button>
```